# Oracle Apex Server Side Condition Type SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to set a server-side condition to an item. I want to check if the user's  input is excisting in the database.

The sql query:

```html
SELECT KAART_CODE FROM CADEAUKAART WHERE KAART_CODE = :P10_KAART_CODE
```

It gives me an ORA-06550: line 1 column 30: ORA-00936: missing expression error.

The query seems fine, i have no idea what i'm doing wrong here.

Hope this screenshot makes more sense:[image: Apex ORA ERROR]

Comment: most  probably `into <a_variable>` part is missing provided the column and table names are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use "Rows returned" condition instead.

[image]

When in doubt about what goes into any of the atrribute values, click on the "Help" tab. There's usually an example.